# CAS - LDAP - error.authentication.credentials.bad

Tags: java, xml, spring, tomcat, cas

I am looking to get CAS to work using LDAP. (FastBind or 2Step Bind) I am using the sAMAccount Name attribute as the username. 
I have installed the following:

JAVA 7
Tomcat 7.0.47
Maven 3.1.1

I also set the proper environment variables successfully for Java, Tomcat, and Maven and installed SSL and imported into keystore successfully.

However, I am at a standstill when trying to get CAS to work with my LDAP server. I am using AD LDS and have connected and

binded authentication successfully without any problems. The CAS server can see the LDAP server via ping.

I can run a maven build successful. I then stop the tomcat service and copy the cas.war file under the target directory into the webapps directory. I have placed the deployer Context Config.xml and `cas.properties` into a new directory `$CATALINA_HOME/work/cas/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`then I started the Tomcat Service.

I can't seem to get LDAP to work. I even commented out the Simple Test Username Password Authentication Handler to avoid usernames to be the same as passwords in the deployer Config Context file.

Here is my `Cas.log` file. Thank you.

```
error.authentication.credentials.bad
TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_NOT_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
```

Comment: Which Ldap authentication handler do you have configured? Can you share your deployerConfigContext.xml file?

Comment: I figured out what the issue was for LDAP. Please mark this as resolved. Thank you.

Comment: can you share deployerConfig.xml please?